# Center text in a table column?

Tags: tables

I have the following table

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\includegraphics{tag.png} & bla bla bla.\\
\includegraphics{tag.png} & \\
\includegraphics{tag.png} & Store project\\
\includegraphics{tag.png} & Gestures\\
\includegraphics{tag.png} & Screenshot\\
\includegraphics{tag.png} & Tagging\\
\end{tabular}
```

Now I'd like to achieve that the second column consumes all the remaining page width and the text should be centered vertically in the cell. I achieve either one of this but no both together. Any hints?

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx,makecell}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l X @{}}
\makecell{\includegraphics{tag.png}} & bla bla bla.\\
\makecell{\includegraphics{tag.png}} & \\
\makecell{\includegraphics{tag.png}} & Store project\\
\makecell{\includegraphics{tag.png}} & Gestures\\
\makecell{\includegraphics{tag.png}} & Screenshot\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Herbert This is basically the same as my solution, except the first column has a specfied width. Why does using lX (with the same redefinition of X) not work?

Comment: @Alan: Because `l` is aligned to its baseline but `m` is aligned to its centerline.

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks i also tried your solution but then I can't generate a PDF: 
<pictures//tag.png, id=198, 54.9553pt x 55.70813pt> <use pictures//tag.png>
<pictures//tag1.png, id=199, 53.44969pt x 54.2025pt> <use pictures//tag1.png>
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 323--324

<use pictures//tag.png> <use pictures//tag.png>
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> ...egin \relax \d@llarend \endtemplate 
                                                  
l.332 \end{tabularx}
                    
?

Comment: @Martin I understand the difference between l and m, but why should the specification of one column (i.e. the l) affect the vertical spacing in the next column which is m?  For example, if you just use `tabular{lm}` the text in the m column is vertically centred.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: you have forgotten a `\\\` at one tabular line or more columns used than specified.

Comment: @Herbert: It's annoying, but in a comment you have to use _double_ backticks if the inline code ends with a backslash: `\`\`\\\`\`` gives ``\\``.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package: (the vertical bars are included just to show the centering).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
 \rule{1in}{1in} & This is some text. This is some more text. This is even more text.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This doesn't do exactly what you want, because it uses two X columns rather than one. For some reason that I don't understand, using

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
```

fails to make the text in the X column vertically centred.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that but i centers horizontally not vertically.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's not exactly what you want, but it might do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Herbert's answer is correct.
However, if you don't want or can't specify the width of the first column you could use the following code and have it measured automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\VC}l<{\endVC}}%
\renewcommand*{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\newbox\mybox
\newenvironment{VC}{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
}{%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \parbox[c]{\wd\mybox}{\usebox\mybox\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{LX}
    \rule{1in}{1in} & Text \\
    \rule{1in}{2in} & Other Text Ag\strut \\
    \rule{1in}{1in} & 
    Very very very very very very very very 
    Very very very very very very very very 
    Very very very very very very very very 
    Very very very very very very very very 
    long text \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see my edited example, it does the same with column type l

Comment: Thanks @Herbert! I didn't know `makecell` before.